# Convert row to a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this and I need to convert the row into a single column

```
PreviousYear   CurrentYear

   2014          2015
```

And I need an output like this

```
Year

2014

2015
```

I am very new to SQL and really appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1125450/2749470)

Comment: You should specify what do you mean by convert. if you need to make new tables and convert data inside, or you just want to select some data to show it in different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION`(will give you distinct values) or `UNION ALL`(won't give you distinct values):

```
SELECT PreviousYear AS 'Year'
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT CurrentYear
FROM tablename
```

This asuming that the two columns `PreviousYear` and `CurrentYear` are of the same data types, other wise an explicit cast will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the general / more complex case, you can use an [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) on the columns to return the data as rows. This has the benefit of providing the columns names in the unpivoted row as well, should you need them:

```
SELECT 
    TheYear
FROM 
    MyTable
UNPIVOT 
(
   TheYear
   for years in ([PreviousYear], [CurrentYear])
) unpvt;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62a4d/4)